# Straight 8 cucumber problems

Tags: diagnosis, soil

I'm new to gardening. I have a container garden on my patio. Everything was started from seed in my kitchen. I planted 3 straight 8 cucumber seedlings in a 18 gal tote.

I used, against better judgement, organic bed soil. A lot has happened since I started in February.  I moved this heavy container in and outside to get it used to the outside conditions of zone 6b (I think). Apparently my patio is on a slope and therefore when watering one day, one side of container ended up with too much water and killed the plant on the side. Now I'm trying to save the other two and realize the soil is too heavy and doesn't allow much air circulation.

I want to amend the soil with maybe some peat moss or something but I'm afraid that I'll only kill the other two. I've heard cucumber roots don't like being disturbed. The plants are over two months old and are around 3 feet tall climbing up trellis.

Comment: What do you mean by too heavy? Plants don't care how heavy soil is so I am assuming you want to be able to lift the pot when the soil is damp? Are you afraid it's going to break the hinges on your balcony or?

Comment: So it's Whitney farms organic raised bed mix and very dense. Its not airy or light. I was told by someone at the store but I should mix peat moss to kind of lighting it up so it can breathe your thoughts...

Comment: I want to know what your concerns are. The general rule of thumb is that if the plants are doing well in the soil then the soil is good for the plants. So as long as the plants are doing well, and your not concerned about the pot weighing too much then there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna go with that. I'm sure I'm just over anxious and worried they'll be ok after one died. But like I said it died due to over watering. You're right. So far they look fine. Thanx for your advice❤

Comment: Np, it is a common theme I have noticed. People are under the impression that plants are hard to grow but in reality, most are exceptionally easy to grow. If I didn't wash my hands so often I wouldn't be surprised to see a few flows pop up out of the dirt in between my finger nails!

Comment: yeah you're right it's usually the humans that create the problems. Thanx again